# Trouble making connections with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm running through the "Your Second iOS App" tutorial on Apple, and I'm on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html).  If you click on the "To connect the text labels to the detail view controller’s properties . . ." section, it explains how to control-click and connect the label to the Table View Controller button in the scene bar below the canvas.  When I do this it doesn't give me an option to name the connection like the tutorial says, it just pops up with the word 'view' and then adds the table view to the list of referencing outlets when I control-click again.

This will obviously make things not work since the labels can't be found by the system, how can I make these connections and am I doing something wrong or is the tutorial wrong?  They seem to be using an older version of Xcode some little things haven't been right.....I'd just like to get past it though, thanks for any help

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Art/drag_in_detail_scene.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since it is only showing `view` and not showing the properties in your class, you either missed the part of the first step "To customize the detail view controller header file . . ." where you added the following lines:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BirdSighting *sighting;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *birdNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
```

**OR**

Under "Design the Detail Scene" you missed the last step under "To replace the default UIViewController scene with a UITableViewController scene . . ." which is:

```
5. In the Custom Class section of the Identity inspector, choose BirdsDetailViewController in the Class pop-up menu.
```

Comment: That's how I've been doing it.  I'm dragging the circle next to "New Referencing Outlet" to the Table View Controller in the bar underneath the View.  When I release the mouse all that pops up is a box that says 'view' in lowercase which I also thought was really odd.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have set your viewController as the same type of the class where you declare the labels.

Then what you need to do is control-click in the Table View Controller button in the scene bar below and then connect the label, the menu will pop up and then you can select the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using the same name (case-Sensitive) in Birds Detail View Controller -> Identity Inspector -> Class. "name" with the code in birdsDetailViewController.h: "@interface "name" : UITableViewControlle"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the posted solutions didn't work. For me, the problem was that I kept trying to make a connection from the Table View Cell rather than from the Label. When you control-click, make sure that the heading of the pop-up says "Label - Detail" rather than e.g. "Table View Cell" or "Content View".