# Why table view not showing any data in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When parsing a local XML file i can see the data in console using NSLog. While in the simulator am getting only the plain table view without any data parsed from xml. Am not understanding where am missing it.

[image: StoryBoard]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];     
     if(cell == nil){    
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];      

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;  
    }  

    theLists = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = theLists.title;  
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please post the code or now you have enough reputation then post the image

Comment: post some code where you are passing your data to tableview.

Comment: @sathya  now you can post your image , what you want to show.

Comment: you can add the image to a public share service and add the link on your question, posting the code will also be useful to get an answer

Comment: Post some code, How you parsing and how you loading/reloading data

Comment: Did you use InterfaceBuilder and set the delegate/datasource of your tableview?

Comment: Have you implemented delegate and datasource?

Comment: @andrea:yes i implemented the datasource and delegate too

Comment: First of all check all your datasource and delegate to be confirmed that you are not wrong those points if those are correct just try 
Taking
 NSString *textval = theLists.title;
check if the textval has any value or not.

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS: I use NSXMLParser for parsing from local xml file. in log it shows me the count of elements in xml correctly but not showing it in iphone as table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer finally where i didn't properly connected the tableview controller class with corresponding controller. I followed the link [Trouble making connections with story board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017767/trouble-making-connections-with-storyboard)

And finally it showed the data in the table view. 
Hope this answer might help others. Thanks for all the people who gave their suggestions in this post.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not reloading your table view.
after completing your parsing just reload your table view.

[reload tablename];

then check your table view delegates are calling or not after this method.
I think this will help you.

happy coding.

Comment: I had reloaded it already here that code - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are reloading in the DidLoad.But After parsing and getting the data from xml, You have to reload that data with TableView.

```
[yourtableView reloadData];
```

Before doing thing, be sure that you have set Delegate and DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two expected reasons for that:

1- May be the number of sections and number of row are not set with the correct value.

2- may be you need to reload the table view data.

Please check these two methods:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return 5; // or any number you want

}
```

Comment: i used the  return value in table view like this                      return [app.listArray count] also i tried directly giving the count of elements as you said return 5  both the possibility shows me no change

Comment: I tried the exact video i listed below to try this xml parsing kindly check it.                                                 Part -1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PZlaDVsLBk&list=UUnwqFfbldaQUIcHneCjf1gQ&index=5&feature=plcp              Part -2  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WpPgy2nbbI&list=UUnwqFfbldaQUIcHneCjf1gQ&index=3&feature=plcp              Part -3  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9higZGafnD4&list=UUnwqFfbldaQUIcHneCjf1gQ&index=4&feature=plcp

Answer (score 0):

Figured I should add this, if you are having trouble with data not showing up or loading.

Make sure your tableview delegate and data source are set to self.

So in the viewcontroller's viewDidLoad() function, make sure you add

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```